# Can't deploy with Capistrano - Issue with Capistrano rvm and bundler

Tags: ruby-on-rails, capistrano

Hi to everyone and thank you for coming to help, here is the issue, im trying to deploy a website with capistrano, the gems and dependencies where too updated so i had to update a lot of this website but no matter what i do i always get this error when trying to do a deploy with Bundle exec cap production deploy. Im using a AWS EC2 Ubuntu 16.04 server

I already did a reinstall of bundler, reinstall of ruby, restarted my terminal, capistrano/rvm and capistrano/bundler is added and required on Capfile

```
00:11 bundler:install
      01 ~/.rvm/bin/rvm  do bundle install --path /home/web/apps/catalog/shared/bundle --jobs 4 --without development test --deployment --quiet
#<Thread:0x00000000017b12a8@/home/ubuntu/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.5.3@catalogIndustry/gems/sshkit-1.19.1/lib/sshkit/runners/parallel.rb:10 run> terminated with exception (report_on_exception is true):
Traceback (most recent call last):
        1: from /home/ubuntu/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.5.3@catalogIndustry/gems/sshkit-1.19.1/lib/sshkit/runners/parallel.rb:11:in `block (2 levels) in execute'
/home/ubuntu/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.5.3@catalogIndustry/gems/sshkit-1.19.1/lib/sshkit/runners/parallel.rb:15:in `rescue in block (2 levels) in execute': Exception while executing as web@ec2-52-15-226-151.us-east-2.compute.amazonaws.com: bundle exit status: 1 (SSHKit::Runner::ExecuteError)
bundle stdout: `rvm do bundle install --path /home/web/apps/catalog/shared/bundle --jobs 4 --without development test --deployment --quiet` was removed, use `rvm 1.9.2,1.9.3 do bundle install --path /home/web/apps/catalog/shared/bundle --jobs 4 --without development test --deployment --quiet` or `rvm all do bundle install --path /home/web/apps/catalog/shared/bundle --jobs 4 --without development test --deployment --quiet` instead.

bundle stderr: Nothing written
(Backtrace restricted to imported tasks)
cap aborted!
SSHKit::Runner::ExecuteError: Exception while executing as web@ec2-52-15-226-151.us-east-2.compute.amazonaws.com: bundle exit status: 1
bundle stdout: `rvm do bundle install --path /home/web/apps/catalog/shared/bundle --jobs 4 --without development test --deployment --quiet` was removed, use `rvm 1.9.2,1.9.3 do bundle install --path /home/web/apps/catalog/shared/bundle --jobs 4 --without development test --deployment --quiet` or `rvm all do bundle install --path /home/web/apps/catalog/shared/bundle --jobs 4 --without development test --deployment --quiet` instead.

bundle stderr: Nothing written


Caused by:
SSHKit::Command::Failed: bundle exit status: 1
bundle stdout: `rvm do bundle install --path /home/web/apps/catalog/shared/bundle --jobs 4 --without development test --deployment --quiet` was removed, use `rvm 1.9.2,1.9.3 do bundle install --path /home/web/apps/catalog/shared/bundle --jobs 4 --without development test --deployment --quiet` or `rvm all do bundle install --path /home/web/apps/catalog/shared/bundle --jobs 4 --without development test --deployment --quiet` instead.

bundle stderr: Nothing written

Tasks: TOP => deploy:updated => bundler:install
(See full trace by running task with --trace)
The deploy has failed with an error: Exception while executing as web@ec2-52-15-226-151.us-east-2.compute.amazonaws.com: bundle exit status: 1
bundle stdout: `rvm do bundle install --path /home/web/apps/catalog/shared/bundle --jobs 4 --without development test --deployment --quiet` was removed, use `rvm 1.9.2,1.9.3 do bundle install --path /home/web/apps/catalog/shared/bundle --jobs 4 --without development test --deployment --quiet` or `rvm all do bundle install --path /home/web/apps/catalog/shared/bundle --jobs 4 --without development test --deployment --quiet` instead.

bundle stderr: Nothing written


** DEPLOY FAILED
** Refer to log/capistrano.log for details.
```

What else can i do to resolve this error and deploy the website?

Comment: try : go to your app folder in sever and bundle install

Comment: Bundle complete! 77 Gemfile dependencies, 183 gems now installed.
Gems in the group test were not installed.
Use `bundle info [gemname]` to see where a bundled gem is installed.

But it says the same error

Comment: sorry i forgot to tell you, bundle install in production environment

Comment: I did and nothing yet, can't see where the issue is

Answer (score 0):

Seems that Capistrano can't determine correct RVM `ruby` version. You can point it by hand

```rb
# deploy.rb 
set :rvm_ruby_version, '2.5.3'
# or if you have single ruby version
set :rvm_ruby_version, 'default'
```